# mysql pass field value into other select query

Tags: mysql, subquery

My query code like this, i want pass value from field `TH_G_RESN_1` to subquery. Please help me thank you
This part work when hard code

```
SELECT temp.TH_G_RESN_1, temp.TH_G_RESN_2,
(select * from (
        select 3  as num 
        UNION SELECT 2 
) AS smallest order by num asc limit 0,1)
FROM as_thin_reason_detail_data temp WHERE apc_id = 656
```

When i pass `TH_G_RESN_1` into subquery `Unknown column 'TH_G_RESN_1' in 'field list'`

```
SELECT temp.TH_G_RESN_1, temp.TH_G_RESN_2,
(select * from (
        select temp.TH_G_RESN_1  as num 
        UNION SELECT temp.TH_G_RESN_2
) AS smallest order by num asc limit 0,1)
FROM as_thin_reason_detail_data temp WHERE apc_id = 656
```

Comment: Remove intermediate `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific record and by default the smallest one then you can order by that conditions and take the first result set

```
SELECT TH_G_RESN_1, TH_G_RESN_2
FROM as_thin_reason_detail_data 
ORDER BY case when apc_id = 656 
              then 1
              else 2 
         end,
         num asc 
limit 1
```